# Twilio - Detect when user starts talking

Tags: node.js, twilio, ivr, twilio-twiml

I've integrated [Twilio in a NodeJS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install) application and I want to know if  there is any way to detect using TwiML when a user starts talking while in the middle of a playback or when the synthesizer is talking? Like when you call to an IVR and the IVR is talking to you and you already know what to say and instead of waiting for it to finish you choose the option right away.

Comment: Hello! Can you share the code you're currently working with and anything you may have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Twilio does not support speech or voice recognition.

Source: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/does-twilio-support-speech-recognition

If

> choose the option right away

means a key press, then you don't have to wait for the playback to finish.